# how to read multiple .xlsx files from multiple subfolders using python

Tags: pandas, os.walk, read.csv

I have one folder that includes 10-12 subfolders, from each subfolder I need to read a specific .xlsx file. I am stuck, I have got all the .xlsx files I want to use `os.walk` but I don't know how to proceed further.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith("abc.xlsx"):
```

Answer (score 0):

I You would like to us os.walk, this is how.

```
import os
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    reqfiles = [i for i in files if i.endswith("abc.xlsx")]
```

You can use just os.listdir.

```
reqfiles = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if i.endswith("abc.xlsx")]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the code , i tried but its not working.